# Delaunay triangulation libraries for sets of 3D points CGAL

Tags: c++, libraries, 3d, delaunay-triangulation

I need help. Do you know such a library for 3D triangulation - CGAL? How to get from it the order of joining the vertices to enter into your variable? Found nothing on the official site. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of joining the vertices"?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of CGAL, but have you tried [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/index.jsp?id=TetGen&lang=1)?

Comment: actually, I don't understand how to use it (what functions to call for triangulation)

Comment: Read its documentation? (http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/index.html). Seems pretty decent to me.

Comment: Yeah. I read this, but also cant understand. ))

Comment: If you google with "tetgen examples", there are lots of hits. I don't use tets in my code, but hexahedra, so I can't help you use tetgen, I only knew that it existed.